# React-bootstrap Navbar with router dom Navlinks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, routes, react-router-v4, reactstrap

I'm trying to use reactstrap navbar from there 
https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/navbar/
with router v4.

Here is my code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Navbar, Nav } from 'react-bootstrap';
import { NavLink } from 'react-router-dom';
import './customnavbar.css'

class CustomNavbar extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Navbar style={{backgroundColor : '#1e272e'}} expand="lg">
        <Navbar.Brand style={{color : 'white' }} href="/">Vincent Sérièges</Navbar.Brand>
        <Navbar.Toggle style={{backgroundColor : 'white' }} aria-controls="basic-navbar-nav" />
        <Navbar.Collapse id="basic-navbar-nav">
          <Nav className="mr-auto" style={{ width:'100%', textAlign:'center', justifyContent : 'flex-end'}}>
            <NavLink style={{color : 'white', paddingRight:'25px', paddingLeft:'25px' }} to="/">Home</NavLink>
            <NavLink style={{color : 'white', paddingRight:'25px', paddingLeft:'25px'  }} to="/portfolio">Portfolio</NavLink>
            <NavLink style={{color : 'white', paddingRight:'25px', paddingLeft:'25px'  }} to="/about">About</NavLink>
            <NavLink style={{color : 'white', paddingRight:'25px', paddingLeft:'25px'  }} to="/contact">Contact</NavLink>
          </Nav>
        </Navbar.Collapse>
      </Navbar>
    );
  }
}

export default CustomNavbar;
```

You can see the result on this link : 
http://vincentserieges.com/

When you click on the menu items the routing works perfectly, but when you refresh the page 
The requested URL /portfolio was not found on this server.

Can anyone guide me in this trouble ?

PS: The routing works perfectly on the webpack-dev-server

Comment: Please include your code directly in the question in text format instead of linking to external images. It most likely works in development because [`historyApiFallback`](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserverhistoryapifallback) is set to `true`. In production you have to configure your server to serve the `index.html` file for every route

Comment: I just edited my post, sorry, thanks for your answer i'm going to try this, Do you have any sources for me cause i'm new and i must admit that i don't really know where i can find the line to configure this

Comment: My bad i just found something, thanks for your answer Tholle.